# Дамп базы MySql Java Ubuntu

Tags: java, mysql, ubuntu, резервное-копирование

Есть такой код `Java`:

```
String PATH = "";

if(WebRequest.isUnix()) {
    PATH = SEPARATOR+"backup";
} else {
    PATH = System.getProperty("ROOT_DIR")+SEPARATOR+"backup";
}

File BACKUP_DIR = new File(PATH);

BACKUP_DIR.mkdir();

LOGGER.info("BACKUP DIR - "+BACKUP_DIR);

File FILE = new File(BACKUP_DIR+SEPARATOR+"backup"+new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())+".sql");

if(FILE.exists()) {
    Files.deleteIfExists(FILE.toPath());
}

LOGGER.info("BACKUP FILE - "+FILE);

String CMD = "";

if(WebRequest.isUnix()) {
    CMD = "/usr/bin/mysqldump --host=localhost --user=root --password=root bitstep > "+FILE.getPath();
} else {
    CMD = "E:\\Programs\\Xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysqldump.exe -u root -p root --database test -r " + FILE.getPath();
}

LOGGER.info("EXECUTE COMMAND - "+CMD);

if(!CMD.isEmpty()) {
    Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(CMD);
    int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

    if (processComplete == 0) {
        LOGGER.info("Backup Complete");
    } else {
        LOGGER.info("Backup Failure");
    }
}
```

Система `Ubuntu 16.04`. По почему-то не срабатывает. Если я выполню команду через консоль `SSH`, то все нормально, а так нет. Ошибок нет, ничего нет.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: `а так нет` - это значит, что ты пытаешься на локальной машине выполнить код?

Comment: @donRumata нет. это значит что на рабочей машине файл не появляется.

Comment: Я просто пытаюсь выяснить где ты это запускаешь, потому что в `WebRequest.isUnix` написано `--host=localhost`. Соответственно, если при выполнении по ssh у тебя всё ок, потому что на той стороне есть  mysql, то на локальной машине скуля нет и ничего не происходит.

Comment: @donRumata на моей машине и на той машине база локальная.

Comment: @donRumata решение нашел.

Answer (score 0):

Решено:

```
String[] cmdarray = {"/bin/sh","-c",command}; 
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray);
```

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28694869/4444092